# Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...........welcome.php on line 15

Tags: phpmyadmin

im still newbie to PHP and mySql, and then i learn by typing all this but the result is : Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/k1424852/public_html/welcome.php on line 15  , and then i search around, but nothing come solution :(, im getting stressed :( , please help ...

```
<?php session_start();
include('config.php');?>
<html>
<head>
<title> My Data </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<p class="welcome" id="greeting">
        <?php           
            $usercheck=$_POST["username"];
            $passcheck=$_POST["password"];
            $db_query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$usercheck."'");
            if (mysql_num_rows($db_query) == 1){  *//<----- line 15*
                $record = mysql_fetch_array($db_query);
                if (md5($passcheck) == $record['password']){
                    echo "Welcome, ". $usercheck ."! You are now logged in.<br/>";
                    $_SESSION['user']= $usercheck;
                    $_SESSION['pass']= $passcheck;
                    }
                else
                    echo "Sorry, wrong password. <br/>";
            }
            else
                echo "Sorry, wrong username.<br/>";
        ?>
<a href="index.php">Click here </a>to return to the main page.
<?php include("footer.php"); ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

thank you so much for your help, i really want to learn but there's no mentor if im getting false .:( thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

dbquery in LINE 14 is failing and returning false.so you are getting that error.

you should check like this.

```
$db_query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$usercheck."'");
if($db_query && mysql_num_rows($db_query) == 1)
```

Comment: yes. i finally found the error, which is my table is not users, instead my_data . and i resetting the config.php which is something not quite yet about the server's name, database name and password. thank you guys. :)